# Absolutely summable signals

Tags: discrete-signals, transfer-function

Given an absolutely summable signal $x[n]$, the $z$-transform $X^z(z)$ is rational with a pole at $z=0.5$.

Given the following the statements:

- $x[n]$ has a finite support in the time domain.
- $x[n]$ is a left sided signal.
- $x[n]$ is a right sided signal.
- $x[n]$ is a two sided signal.

Can anyone please tell which statements are true and explain why or why not?

Comment: I know I'm a nitpicker, but *systems* have transfer functions, signals don't. But, that's just semantics; in the end, all we care about is that $X$ is the $z$-Transform of $x$.

Comment: You are all right, edited :).

Comment: These kind of questions should be worded carefully to remove undecidable ambiguity as much as possible and to clearly underline the range of decidable unknowns about the quantity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute summability implies that the Fourier transform converges uniformly, so this means that the unit circle is contained in the region of convergence (ROC).

Now, the pole at 0.5 is the limit of the ROC, so the ROC is from 0.5 outwards (in order to include the unit circle). This means that the signal is right-sided.

Finite support signals cannot have poles (other than $z=0$ or $z=\infty$).

Comment: But it also can be two sided right?

Comment: @SamaAssi: No, it can't be two-sided because for that you'd need another pole outside the unit circle. For two-sided signals the ROC is an annulus centered at the origin of the complex plane.

Comment: Since the signal is absolutely summable we can conclude that z=1 is inside the ROC, so if we choose for example the signal $x[n]=\frac{1}{2}^{|n|}$ it would be two sided with a suitable ROC no?

Comment: Hi: the z-transform ( which is really just the closed form of the infinite series ) of your example is $\frac{1}{1- 0.5 z}$ if you sum from $0$ to $\infty$.. If you sum in the other direction,  -n,  the infinite series doesn't converge. So, I'm not absolutely sure but I think that's why it's called right sided. Someone hopefully will confirm.

Comment: @SamaAssi: Yes, a two-sided signal can be absolutely summable; my comment was about your question where you have a single pole. Your example of a two-sided signal has two poles, but it is indeed abolutely summable. As long as the unit circle is inside the ROC the signal is absolutely summable, no matter if it's right-sided, left-sided, or two-sided.

Comment: @Matt l: No need to be kind. Is my comment totally wrong !!!!

Comment: @markleeds: I don't think your comment is totally wrong, there should just be a $z^{-1}$ in the denominator instead of a $z$. The corresponding sequence is indeed right-sided if it is known that it's absolutely summable, because then the unit circle $|z|=1$ is inside the ROC.

Comment: The question does not explicitly say that the signal's Z-transform has only a single pole as it says "which statement**s**" are true?" creating some ambiguity. However it naturally reads that way you interpreted. If that were the case, then yes, the signal can only be right sided to be abs summable. Yet as @Sama indicates it could also be two sided by allowing a second a pole outside the unit circle. I think the question should be worded better.

Comment: Matt: That mistake was due to a notational difference between econometrics where  L is used in place of $z^{-1}$. My mistake and  I'd fix it but I don't think one can fix comments after a certain time passes.  Thanks.